# Chrome Extension Licensing System

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, license-key

I am currently developing a chrome extension and need to make sure it will only be run as 1 instance per license key. Basically, I am planning on selling the extension in limited amounts online and providing customers with a license key upon purchase. How can I ensure that the extension is only running on one computer at a time (sharing of license keys is against our terms of service)? I need to be as sure as possible that the extension cannot be cracked but am at a loss for the simplest way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you not check with your server how many instances are being run? Ultimately checking on your server is going to be safer than on the client, where you can just do something superficial in the UI to notify the user

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution will be to add an unique encripted key send by the server in response to the activation from the app, than when opening the app checking this encrypt key from the server and block it if don't match.
Obviously if the activation key already exist in the server the encrypt key will not be sent and the app will not activate to prevent multi pc instance.

The only problem will be create a backup mail recovery system to reset the encrypt key when changing pc or after app disinstallation.